# bootstrap modal toggle jquery validate resetForm

Tags: jquery, validation, modal-dialog, toggle

I have some Bootstrap 3 modals that use contact forms.
The simplest modal just opens the contact form, some jquery validate and ajax php occurs. If the user decides to close the form without completing their request, I have some jquery in my footer that clears the form:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("form").validate().resetForm();
})
```

However, I have some other modals that toggle between content and a contact form and the above code won't clear the form, so any user entered data/jquery validate messages are still there if they re-open it.

I have tried a number of suggestions to clear the data, but can't get anywhere with it.

I have also tried:

```
$(this).removeData('bs.modal');
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
  $("form").validate().resetForm();
})
```

Why can't I clear the data inside a toggled div?

Thanks

Comment: This might help, I just realised that it's only clearing the first form of 7, all forms reuse the same code.

Answer (score 4):

Clearing both validation error messages and inputs in a modal when you clicked "Cancel" button.

```
    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
        $("form").each(function(){
            $(this).validate().resetForm();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                $('form')[0].reset();
            };
```

example

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            $('form')[0].reset();
        };    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name='text1' />
<input type="text" name='text2' />
</form> 

<a href="http://www.space.com/" >fly out into space</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, sussed it!
Needed to make sure EACH form was reset, this works:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("form").each(function(){
      $(this).validate().resetForm();
    });
});
```